# Hot to hide this button on widget?

Tags: qt, button, qwidget

I know it is possible to call `setFixedSize()` to widget and it will be "inactive" but i want to know is it possible to hide it at all.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean 'status bar'?

Comment: @bogdyname this is a button that responds to the size of the window, it is located in the lower right corner of the widget.

Comment: Can you show full screenshot of the app or objects of UI?

Comment: @bogdyname pasted whole screen image into edit.

Comment: remove QStatusBar

Comment: @Gaurav Goswami is it help (about my answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try like this in constructor of MainWindow class:

```
this->statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```